# Entity Framework SaveChanges - update - using just the primary key

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I used SQL Profiler to trace the SQL generated by Entity Framework to update a change to an entity. I don't understand why it generates all the other conditions when it is already using the primary key.

Can you explain why and how to make it use just the primary key in the where clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the context has been updated between retreiving and updating the entity.

It'll throw an `OptimisticConcurrencyException` if 0 rows are returned from the update, which means the entity in the context has been modified.

How did you create your models? [This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/05/20/tip-19-how-to-use-optimistic-concurrency-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) might explain it a bit; columns that have a Concurrency Mode of Fixed will be included in the where clause.

Comment: thank you CodeCaster.. the columns in my model are set to the default concurrency mode of 'None', but they still show up in the where clause..